# Insert a link in each image of carousel in R with jQuery

Tags: jquery, r, flexdashboard

I tried add a link in each image of a carousel in R. My code (the images is not reproducible. You must use an image from your computer):

````
---
title: "Statistics"
runtime: shiny
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
    theme: spacelab
---

```{r}
library(flexdashboard)
library(shiny)
library(broom)
library(scales)
library(kableExtra)
library(bsplus)
library(htmltools)
```

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
===========================================

Column {}
-------------------------------------------

```{r}
bs_carousel(id = "the_beatles", use_indicators = 
TRUE) %>%
  bs_append(
content = bs_carousel_image(src = "img/image_2.jpg"),
caption = bs_carousel_caption("John Lennon", "Rhythm guitar, vocals")
  ) %>%
  bs_append(
content = bs_carousel_image(src = "img/image_1.jpg"),
caption = bs_carousel_caption("Paul McCartney", "Bass guitar, vocals")
  )
```
````

- How insert a clickable link in each image of carousel (`image_1` and `image_2`)?

For example, by clicking in carousel `image_1` the user is directed to the website *www.stackoverflow.com*; and if clicking in carousel `image_2` the user is directer to website *www.google.com*.

To place the same link on **all images**, I put this code (`jQuery`) below the `YAML` header:

```
<script>
$('.carousel-inner>.item>img').wrap('<a href = "https://www.stackoverflow.com" 
target = "_blank">');
</script>
```

But, I want a link for each image.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this script:

```
<script>
var urls = ["https://www.stackoverflow.com", "https://www.google.com"]
$('.carousel-inner>.item>img').wrap(function(i){
return '<a href = "' + urls[i] + '" target = "_blank">'
});
</script>
```

Comment: Wonderful, @Stéphane. +50